# change width of input field depending on browser?

Tags: html, css

i have an input field and i want it to be 2 different sizes in internet explorer and firfox if possible, the code i have right now is:

```
div.search input#query {

  width: 450px;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

so i want somthing like this:

```
div.search input#query {

if internet explorer {  width: 450px;}
else {  width: 350px;}
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to target a specific directly in a clean way (without CSS hacks) except for Internet Explorer that is aware of [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

You could put all the IE specific properties into a separate style sheet and embed that after the main stylesheet (so it overwrites the existing settings):

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

you will probably want to discriminate between various versions of IE, as IE 6, 7 and 8 tend to behave differently in many respects.

Comment: that would work for me great, how can i embed that after the main stylesheet (so it overwrites the existing settings)? sorry but im new to css and web development.

Comment: @Mo just put the above code into the `head` section of the document after the directive you use to embed your main style sheet (if you are using an external stylesheet?)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this script :

http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

after you include this script you can easy use in the css.

Comment: This is very nice, but the JavaScript requirement is a big downside IMO.